# How to highlight the same C++ variable on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using C++ coding editor on Visual Studio 2010.
I remember the IDE will help highlight the same variables when I selected a variable.But it doesn't work now.

I have enabled the "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" on the C/C++ option.

And it doesn't help showing the members of the namespace when I type the "." or "->".

Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, highlighting the same variable is not available for C++ in Visual Studio 2010. However, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/08/24/10200097.aspx) does indicate that it will be available in the next version after VS 2010

Comment: What about the "showing the members of the namespace when I type the "." or "->".  "

Answer (score 1):

This extension does more or less what you want:

**Highlight all occurrences of selected word**
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb

Double click on a word, and it will highlight all other occurrences of that word. Not that the highlighted occurrences can include commented-out code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to that problem
there is a column that has the numbers of your lines of code "it's next to your lines of code", just press right-click on this column, then choose "Preferences", then show the list of "editor", then press on the "Mark Occurrences", then mark on all options which will show up to you.